# how I can edit the asp.net mvc project direct from ftp using visual studio 12?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ftp, project

I have a mvc3 project on ftp server. The project is live runing. I want to edit the views without downloading them. I want to edit the file direct on FTP.

Have any clue how i can edit the file direct on FTP using Visual Studio.

---

I got a good sollution called Komodo Edit. What I want is simple edit my aspx razor file so Going with Komodo Edit is a  good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to edit the views without downloading them. I want to edit the file direct on FTP.

That does not exist. You must download a file before you can edit it, and re-upload it when done. There are IDE's and FTP programs that abstract this behavior by using a kind of temp folder and a FileSystemWatcher, but to my knowledge this isn't built in to Visual Studio.

And that is a good thing, because you do not want to edit live files through the IDE. How will you revert an accidental file deletion or other screwup? Use versioning, work locally, test locally, then publish to the server.